# Keycloak does not work on https after setting up SSL

Tags: ssl, keycloak

I have a problem where I don´t know why it happens.

I have LetsEncrypt Certificates which I use to create a .pfx file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out /tmp/certificate.pfx -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/cert.pem -certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/chain.pem
```

I set up keycloak 8.0.1. as service by following this tutorial (https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-keycloak-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-ed8c7c79a2d9) and it worked fine. Keycloak seems to set up a self-signed certificate which is not what I want. First I set up Keycloak for SSL.

With the JBoss-cli.sh file I do the following (described here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#setting-up-https-ssl)

```
    /core-service=management/security-realm=UndertowRealm:add()
    /core-service=management/security-realm=UndertowRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path=keycloak.jks, keystore-relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir, keystore-password=secret)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=security-realm, value=UndertowRealm)
```

Not my security tealm looks like this:

```
    <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
        <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore path="keycloak.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secret"/>
            </ssl>
        </server-identities>
    </security-realm>
```

I import the certificate now:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /tmp/certificate.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Then I restart keycloak:

```
systemctl restart keycloak
```

Now I get the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 502

You can also check the network tab of my website if that helps.

The keycloak service is up and running, however it seems it does not work on port 8443 anymore.

Listener look like this:

```
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </host>
    </server>
```

Any idea why this happens? Are my certificates wrong? I´m quite desperate with Keycloak already :-(

Edit:

This is my logged Error:

> ]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.UndertowRealm.key-manager"
>   => "WFLYDM0018: Unable to start service
>       Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key"}} 2019-12-23 19:12:57,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed
>   "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
>   2019-12-23 19:12:57,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller
>   Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report WFLYCTL0186:
>   Services which failed to start:      service
>   org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.UndertowRealm.key-manager:
>   WFLYDM0018: Unable to start service WFLYCTL0448: 2 additional services
>   are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed 2019-12-23
>   19:12:57,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server 2019-12-23 19:12:57,578 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management
>   interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management 2019-12-23
>   19:12:57,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
>   2019-12-23 19:12:57,580 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0026: Keycloak 8.0.1 (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started (with
>   errors) in 41093ms - Started 586 of 888 services (4 services failed or
>   missing dependencies, 604 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the keystore is incorrectly generated. Check that:

- You set the value of `keystore-password` to match actual keystore password.
- You set alias `root` for root certificate.
- You set alias `yourdomain.com` for the domain certificate.

Try to follow the steps exactly as described in the documentation.

Comment: With documentation you mean the link? I did not use a self-signed certificate, but one from LetsEncrypt. Is that a difference? I would so very grateful if you could show me the steps. I have not much of a clue of SSL

Comment: Yeah, in the first step you generated keystore with private key, you can use this private key to create CSR for letsencrypt. After you get certificates from letsencrypt just import them in the keystore. I found a good step-by-step guide for WildFly (Keycloak works on top of WildFly) https://github.com/antoniopaolacci/Let-s-Encrypt-Certificate-and-JBoss-WildFly

Comment: I got it working. My keystore was indeed wrong. Now I´m facing a new problem :-)